# Why is jQuery ajax response always filled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I noticed that the response of an ajax call with jQuery is never empty. I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        data: { data },
        url: "phpFile",
        datatype: 'text'
 }).done(function( response ) {             

        if (response.length > 2)
        alert(response);
    });
```

in the php file I only return text if there is an error with a query

```
echo mysqli_error($conn);
```

however even when I don't return anything the length is always 2 or greater, does someone knows why or how could I retrieve an empty text?

Comment: What is the content?

Comment: response should be a text indicating whether it is success or error, including other context. Do you see the context of `response` as you alert it?

Comment: when I alert it only shows blank, however the length is 2

Comment: Try response.trim first then check length hope this work for you

Comment: Instead of check response.length > 2, return some value from your ajax response.& validate it inside `.done()`

Comment: Use `console.log(response)` instead of `alert(response)`. This will allow you to inspect the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question just to serve as reference for anyone seeing this.

What I was trying to do was actually a bad practice and the best thing to do as *Dipanwita Kundu* mentioned is to return a proper success response, `false` or `true` with error message.

Comment: But this answer doesn't respond the question.